# Access object enabler via RealDWG engine

Tags: autocad, custom-object

I'm trying to open a dwg file containing custom objects from another application using RealDWG . Has anyone aware of any documentations or sample / video of how to access the object enabler of that particular application to read object's internal data?

Thanks,
Afshin

proposed tags: RealDWG Object-Enabler